# PyQt4 "Mainwindow.show()" gives an Type error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, twisted

i'm creating an application in python where the front end has been made in pyqt4 and the backend has been made in twisted . when i try to run the code the show function throws an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ABHISHEK\Desktop\teest\cort1.py", line 358, in <module>
    MainWindow.show(reactor)
TypeError: QWidget.show(): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'
```

the code :

```
 __name__ == "__main__":
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

try:
    import qt4reactor
except ImportError:
    from twisted.internet import qt4reactor
qt4reactor.install()

from twisted.internet import reactor
MainWindow=QtGui.QMainWindow
ui = Ui_MainWindow(reactor)
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

reactor.run()
```

this is the code for the class Ui_MainWindow:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,reactor, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.reactor=reactor
        self.pf = Factory()
        self.pf.protocol = Protocol
        self.reactor.listenTCP(3609, self.pf) # listen on port 1234

    def setupUi(self,MainWindow):
        MainWindow=QtGui.QMainWindow()
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(903, 677)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        #then rest of the ui components.
```

can anyone tell me why the show() function is throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not instantiate `QtGui.QMainWindow`. I modified your code: (See comments)

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
_fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8

class Ui_MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,reactor, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.reactor=reactor
        self.pf = Factory()
        self.pf.protocol = Protocol
        self.reactor.listenTCP(3609, self.pf) # listen on port 1234

    def setupUi(self,MainWindow):
        #MainWindow=QtGui.QMainWindow() # <-- Just use passed MainWindow.
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(903, 677)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        #then rest of the ui components.

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    try:
        import qt4reactor
    except ImportError:
        from twisted.internet import qt4reactor
    qt4reactor.install()

    from twisted.internet import reactor
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow() # <-- Instantiate QMainWindow object.
    ui = Ui_MainWindow(reactor)
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    reactor.run()
```

Comment: corrected the problem , but now  "MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow")) "is giving the same error when setupUi is being called.

Comment: @thecreator232, I updated the code with the code that I tested myself. With above code, no error occured.